# How do you change the apn for a mobile broadband connection

Tags: 11.10, networking, usb, network-manager, broadband

When I connect the Pantech UML290 (Verizon 4G LTE) device to ubuntu 11.10 it recognizes the device but it doesn't let me change the APN.  The "New Mobile Broadband Connection" Wizard skips the "Choose your Billing Plan" step.  So how do I set/change the APN?

Answer (score 1):

Choose "I can't find my provider, and I wish to enter it manually:" in "Choose your Provider" Type the name of your provider (doesn't matter what you type) Then type your APN in the given text-box.